# Changing the color of an object in an Android application

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

Basically my goal is change the color of object in real time for paint application. To achieve this goal I follow the following concepts:

1. I have used the `canny()` method for finding the object.
2. Using `findContours()` for edge detection.
3. using `drawContours()` for coloring the object.

If there is any other concept required to achieve the goal please
    suggest to me.   I have tried but not getting exact contours edge.

**Original input:**

[image: original image]

**Expected output:**

[image: Expected output]

**Current output:**

[image: getting output]

> I am getting image in gray scale but i want in rgb mode.

**here is my code:**

```java
package com.example.imageprocess;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

        private Mat                    mRgba;
        private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
        private Mat                    mGray;

        private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

        private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    {
                        Log.i("OPENCVACTIVITY", "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                        // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                       // System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

                        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    } break;
                    default:
                    {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    } break;
                }
            }
        };

       /* public MainActivity() {
            Log.i("OPENCVACTIVITY", "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
        }
*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial2_activity_surface_view);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
            mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
            mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
         mRgba.release();
            mGray.release();
            mIntermediateMat.release();

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat gaussian_output = new Mat();
         mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
         Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
         Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
         Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mIntermediateMat, gaussian_output, new Size(5, 5), 5);
         List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
         Imgproc.findContours( gaussian_output, contours, new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0) );
         Scalar color = new Scalar(165, 30, 215);
        // Imgproc.drawContours(gaussian_output, contours, -1, color, 3);
         Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
      // find contours:
      Imgproc.findContours(gaussian_output, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
      for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
          Imgproc.drawContours(gaussian_output, contours, contourIdx,color, -1);
      }

        return gaussian_output;
    }


}
```

Comment: have you found any solution? I'm also trying same but not able to find anything. Can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you made the error of moving the grayscale image to the coloured image.

Try:
`Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);`
Instead of:
`Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);`

Comment: above code is not working ...                                                                                                                  right now I am getting  grayscale  image but i want camera should be opened with colored image and when i touch the particular object then object color be changed

Comment: I still feel as if you are making some grave errors in the onCameraFrame method. You get a rgba and grayscale version of the inputFrame, then you later use the grayscale as an input and the rgba as an outpur effectively overriding it.

Comment: when i tried following code in oncameraFrame()  getting same output, i mean image shows in grayscale                                                                            
         Imgproc.Canny(mRgba, mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);                           
         Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);

Comment: I'm not saying that that is the error it might be something else because you are reseting the rgba to grayscale.

Comment: Could you please put up the project somewhere so that I can mess with it in Eclipse and see if I can get it working?

Comment: could you share your mail id with me

Comment: diedgaming@gmail.com :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81386/discussion-between-prabhakar-and-user2693587).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party. I have not tried the code out, but I suspect:

```
mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

Even though mIntermediateMat is 8bit 4 channel mat here,

```
Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
```

It was turned into a 8bit 1 channel mat here. ref: [canny doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny).

> output edge map; it has the same size and type as image .

As a result,

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mIntermediateMat, gaussian_output, new Size(5, 5), 5);
```

gaussian_output is an 8bit 1 channel mat, and...

```
return gaussian_output;
```

returns an 8 bit 1 channel (grayscale) image.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/libPNG.html

You should use LIBPNG for image processing. Using it you can convert it to grayscale or colored image by setting color matrix.